# Can't load a .bash_profile on windows powershell

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, .bash-profile

I'm looking to load a .bash_profile with some aliases and functions on launch but, I haven't been able to find a way to load the .bash_profile.  I'm not even sure if it is possible.

Comment: .bash_profile is for bash, not Powershell, right? Sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What results do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.

Powershell has some commands aliased to Unix spellings, but they are not otherwise compatible.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if that was the case.  I suppose I'll convert to cygwin.